# in xcode is there a way to programaticly add a custom class?

Tags: swift, cocoa

is there a way to do this https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRZq4.jpg
but programaticly,

i have a nsview class that i'd like to link to my application 
by  adding it as a custom class  by programaticly?

## update:

```
let mymainWindow = NSWindow()


  class keys: NSView{
override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {  
    return  event.keyCode == 53 || event.keyCode == 36 //53 = Escape, 36 = Return 
}
```

i need to add that nsview class as a custom class for mymainWindow
but programaticly

Comment: Do you want to create instances of a class programatically or add a new class definition programatically ? If it is the latter, not sure why you would need it.

Comment: my class nsview class uses override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool , and the only way for it to be linked to my application main window is by adding that class to the custom class field in the nib file but now i made my own window in code so i cant just add it to that field i show in the picture

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: I am not OS X programmer, so take it with a pinch of salt. Create an NSWindow subclass `MyMainWindow`, in the implementation of `MyMainWindow` add `Keys` (your custom view) as a subview. Then use `let mymainWindow = MyMainWindow()`

Comment: It would be better if you learn the basics of macOS programming before creating your app

Comment: Make a custom UIView and use it where u want....

Comment: asim, this is for a macos app not ios

Comment: You don't add the class as a custom class for myMainWindow but create instances of that class for your apps usage.  You appear to be misunderstanding fundamental principles of this kind of programming and I would suggest more time spent on learning the structures of the language and perhaps some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to asking about *substitutability*, a core feature of most (but not all) languages supporting object-oriented design. To quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming stating that, in a computer program, if `S` is a subtype of `T`, then objects of type `T` may be *replaced* with objects of type `S` (i.e. an object of type `T` may be *substituted* with any object of a subtype `S`) without altering any of the desirable properties of `T` (correctness, task performed, etc.).

What this means in your situation is that the `NSView` function which you call to add subviews to a window's content view (or any other view):

```
func addSubview(_ view: NSView)
```

takes as argument an instance of `NSView` *or any of its subclasses*, e.g. the `Keys` class of your example. So using subclasses when writing your own code is simple and direct – you just create an instance of your subclass and use it, including where an instance of its superclass is specified.

> my class nsview class uses override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool , and the only way for it to be linked to my application main window is by adding that class to the custom class field in the nib file but now i made my own window in code so i cant just add it to that field i show in the picture

This is somewhat backwards. In a graphical interface to write code, such as the Interface Designer in Xcode, the designer has to devise a method to enable substitutability so the user can use a subclass just as they would when writing the code by hand. Xcode uses the controls under the "Custom Class" heading you are referring to.

HTH

---

BTW, as you appear to be new to SO: Your question appears to stem from your figuring out how to do something in the graphical interface before comprehending the underlying principles of the programming language, hence the comment from someone:

> It would be better if you learn the basics of macOS programming before creating your app

where they were trying to *help you*. Your response:

> ... dumb comment ...

Is **not** appropriate on SO.